# @Html.validate method, how does it work?

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have written this code for Form Validation and it works perfectly

> The Data Holder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace workflow.DataHolders
{
    public class NewCompany
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage="Length Of The Company Name Should  Be More Than Three Letters")]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Length Of The Country Name Should  Be More Than Two Letters")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> View Side

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/sharedfiles/css/forms/addnew.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="Add_container">

   @if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       <div id="validationMessage">Please Correct The Errors Below</div> 
   }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateAndSignUp", "Accounts", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.ValidationMessage("CompanyName");
        <span class="field_title">Company Name: </span>
        @Html.TextBox("CompanyName")

        @Html.ValidationMessage("Email");
        <span class="field_title">Email: </span>
        @Html.TextBox("Email")



        @Html.ValidationMessage("Country");
        <span class="field_title">Country Name: </span>
        @Html.TextBox("Country")

        <span class="field_title">About The Company: </span>
        @Html.TextArea("Description")



        <input type="submit" value="Create New Account">


    }
</div>
<div class="get_connected_message">
    <h1>Get Connected with your Customers</h1>
</div>

<div class="get_connected_message">
    <h1>Build your profissional buisness world</h1>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

> ValidateAndSignUp Action

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ValidateAndSignUp(NewCompany newCompany)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("signUp", newCompany);
    }
}
```

Every thing Works perfectly and it validates correctly, but I tried to the **@Html.validate** method because I read that it does no thing else it register the field for validation, but what does that mean? does it mean that it register it to be validated in the client side, and if yes, how that could be done?.

Comment: There is no reason to use `@Html.Validate()` (or `ValidateFor()`) if your using `@Html.ValidationMessage()` (or `ValidationMessageFor()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes I know, but I want to understand how does it work?

Comment: I think it force to validate given field that has no  @Html.ValidationMessage() and you can display message on your own...

Answer (score 0):

**@Html.Validate** registers the property for validation without the need to show a message should the validation fail. This HTML helper is only used when you want to trigger validation, but don't want to show a specific error for that control. In your case, since you are already using ValidationMessage, there is no need to use Validate; because the property has been already registered for validation on the ValidationMessage helper.

Also if you have unobtrusive JavaScript enabled **@Html.Validate** will just return without actually doing anything. Because if you do have unobtrusive Javascript, then other mechanisms are going to take care of registering the property for client and server validation.